# Open link in new tab without loading it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to open links in a new tab inside Google Chrome without loading them? And instead, that it would wait for you to manually go to the tab to start loading ? (same philosophy as what Firefox, I suppose. Firefox does this when you open it and it starts where you left off, loading only the first-tab/last-loaded-tab)

Please let me know if there is a way to do that in Google Chrome, either by editing options or by the use of an extension you know off, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be sort-of possible, but it's ugly and you still have to load something.

Basically, you need a bare-bones page that has JavaScript to detect whether or not the page has focus.  You can use the code samples here to determine that:  [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Once the page has focus, you can redirect to the actual page.  This is messy.  Don't do it, unless you have a really good reason.  Your users will hate you for it.

Comment: I am only talking about my own browser. I am talking about tweeking Google chrome to be able to behave this way